# Mapping nested JSON to Model in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I would like to map a model with nested JSON, but it is not recognizing 'message' `id`.

I've searched a lot and can not find what's wrong.

Would also like to create an auto-map data comparing JSON with the model (without need to set each value), is that possible?

---

JSON DATA:

```
{
    "author": "John Doe",
    "message": {
        "id": 32133,
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
    }
}
```

post.model.ts

```
export class PostModel {

  author: string;
  message: PostMessageModel;

  constructor() { }

  convert(data: any) {
    this.author = data.author;
    this.message.id = data.message.id; // ERROR HERE
    this.message.text = data.message.text;
    ...
  }
}

interface PostMessageModel {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
at PostModel.webpackJsonp.343.PostModel.convert (post.model.ts:10)
...
```

Comment: First initiate this.message with something, then you can set its fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.message = {
id: data.message.id,
text: data.message.text
};
```